# SQL query to find available future dates except weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have table called "detail" where i am storing start date and end date of jobs.I have one more table called "leaves" which is also have leave startdate and leave enddate fields.I need to find the nearest available dates of a user without weekends and leave dates.

```
DECLARE @PackagerLastAssignedDate DATETIME

SELECT @PackagerLastAssignedDate = MAX(EndDate)  FROM detail WHERE userId  = 1 

SELECT lveStartDate,lveEndDate  FROM Leaves WHERE UserId = 1 and lveStartDate > @PackagerLastAssignedDate
```

Thanks In advance
Berlin.M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @DateFrom DATETIME
    , @DateTo DATETIME

SELECT 
      @DateFrom = '20130101'
    , @DateTo = '20130202'

SELECT [Date]
FROM (
    SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, sv.number, t.DateFrom)
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              DateFrom = @DateFrom
            , diff = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateFrom, @DateTo)
    ) t
    JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values sv ON sv.number <= diff
    WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'
) t2
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [Date]) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM dbo.Leaves l
        WHERE l.UserId = 1
            AND t2.[Date] BETWEEN l.lveStartDate AND l.lveEndDate 
    )
```

Comment: This will only eliminate the weekends.. I need to avoid some particular dates from other table "Leaves".I need to select next 3 available dates apart from weekend and leaves. Clear....?

Comment: If it needs to rescheduled to some previous date what can I do...
Suppose I need to set @DateFrom to some previous date by checking the same conditions like excluding week end & leave ... How can I succeed that.....